# Is there an actual jython to bytecode compiler à la nuitka?

Tags: jvm, jython, bytecode, nuitka

While Jython offers a neat way to access Java from within Python-ish code, its bytecode works with `PyObject`s etc. and in order to let a Java programm interact with a Jython program, one has to put in [some extra effort](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications) such as writing an object factory.

But is there a way to obtain a `.class` file from Jython code that basically is a valid Java class, i.e. uses Jython's magic at compile time rather than at runtime, similar to [nuitka](/questions/tagged/nuitka). I understand [javac](http://www.jython.org/Project/jythonc.html) was supposed to do this but is now deprecated.

Or should I simply stick with pure Jython and write Java interfaces?

Comment: Python's object model, method resolution, etc. is completely different to Java, so why would you expect to be able to compile it to native Java bytecode? No matter what you do you'll need reflection calls everywhere just to handle the duck typing, multiple inheritance, runtime attribute lookup, descriptors, etc.

Comment: @Antimony of course,but the same holds for Python and C/C++ yet there's nuitka

Comment: I suppose you could do something like nuitka targeting Java bytecode. But it's a lot of work, so I'm not surprised if noone's bothered.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks, I didn't realize [tag:compiler] was replaced by [tag:compiler-construction] - though that might be adequate for a follow-up question...

Comment: @Antimony Probably :/ But maybe one could actually fork off nuitka to obtain a Java code generator...